# Membership.GetUser() vs Context.User

Tags: asp.net, forms, forms-authentication

What are the differences between Membership.GetUser() and Context.User, and which is recommended for use in getting information about the current user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have membership configured for your site, getuser() won't yield anything.

Context.user is the identity token handed to the asp.net runtime, and will yield a user if any authentication aside from anonymous acces is configured fo the site.

Comment: Sounds like you're saying that Membership.GetUser() will get the user from the Membership (obvious enough), whereas Context.User will get the user from a broader scope - anything.  So using windows auth, for example, yields nothing from Membership.GetUser(), but it DOES yield the windows user from Context.User.  (And this appears to be the case from a quick test.)

In that case, which is recommended if you are definitely using a Membership provider?

Comment: The MembershipProvider, in my experience; is mainly used when you need some flexibility in your authentication, you can even have an XMLMembershipProvider if needed.  If you are using forms based authentication, a membershipprovider is probably the most painless way to go about it.

Comment: Looking more deeply into it, it looks like Context.User really gives minimal information.  I think you're right about Membership.GetUser().

Then again, there may be an efficiency drag from using Membership.GetUser() if all you need is information you can get from Context.User.

Answer (score 3):

Membership.GetUser implies the use of a MembershipProvider. It simply retrieves user information from whatever store is configured. (e.g. ActiveDirectory, SQL Server). Context.User is the IPrincipal security context for the current Request.